# Is Red Dwarf crewed by the military?

Tags: red-dwarf

Every so often a character says the ship Red Dwarf belongs to the Jupiter Mining Corporation, yet the personnel and officers are members of a body called the Space Corps- is the Space Corps a military organization, and if so, why is it running a privately owned spacecraft?

Comment: https://reddwarf.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Corps

Comment: Maybe the military outsources their mining operations? though tbh the only military reference I can remember is Todhunter being a lieutenant... and maybe Rimmer wanting to be an officer

Comment: I always saw it as similar to  [the British Merchany Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_Navy_(United_Kingdom)), which while it is commercial has strong military ties and military-like traditions.